# Firebase collections relations in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have in my Firebase a collection named 'users' and inside of it there is a sub-collection named 'students'. Also, I have another collection named 'Courses' that contain a sub-collection named 'sections' and inside this each section there is a list of 'student' that contain some 'students' from the first mentioned sub-collection.

My issue is that I don't know how to make the changes in a student be found in both students sub-collection and the 'studentsList' in the section sub-collection.

[image]

Comment: A diagram would really help us understand your data structure more clearly. Otherwise you're probably going to have to perform two operations. You seem to have slightly relational data needs in a non-relational data.

Comment: i added the diagram for the relation

Comment: I guess you might need to duplicate your data from student sub-collection to Section sub-collection and note one thing you should only use sub-collection if you want to avoid composite indexing and show the data together otherwise use separate collection it would be better

Comment: and what do you mean by `list of students` what are you trying to store in that students uid or something else or your document names are studentList? and what kind of changes are you talking about like the entire collection or only few documents should be in sync?